# Annotations: restrict reference to classes with a annotation

Tags: java, annotations, definition

I think this is not possible, but maybe I'm wrong. So I ask you, if it is possible. ;-)

If I define a annotation that accept only class references which extends some interface or class that is possible:

```
 Class<? extends ServiceProviderIF> serviceIFProvider();
```

At this annotation I only can add some class which extends ServiceProviderIF. **My question: is such a definition also possible for another annotation?** That means with pseudocode something like this

```
 Class<? contains AnnotationXYZ> classReferences();
```

AnnotationXYZ is another annotation definition. And the class which should be added is only accepted by containing this Annotation.

TIA and best regards, Oli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible. Annotation can be set on any type (class, interface), but Java method can't return a multi-type containing types from different hierarchies. In other words, you should place all your classes that have annotation `AnnotationXYZ` in the same hierarchy under some interface or class `Blabla`, then use type `<? extends Blabla>` wildcard.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but that make the process more complicated and adds IMHO no benefit. The reason is to ensure that all elements inside this annotation list will have a specific annotation X (this annotation X have some additional information). So if the class extends a special interface there is no benefit for take care to add only classes with this annotation. Or I'm wrong? Best regards, Oli

Comment: Method return type specifies some kind of contract between caller and callee. AFAIK, annotations are not designed for use in contracts.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. Only types are accepted in generic types. And annotations don't define types.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The syntax is only pseudocode. Some other syntax is also welcome to get a solution ... for example:
Class<?> classReferences() with AnnotationXYZ;

Comment: There is no notation that can allow you to do that. Only runtime checks.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, thats the way I do it at the moment. But the information about the Annotation needs to be present at JVM (@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)). Thats not that nice, but if there is no other way to do that it's "best practise". Thanks and greetings, Oli