# How to implement a Spring Data repository for a @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, generics, jpa, spring-data

I've got a JPA `@MappedSuperClass` and an `@Entity` extending it:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private Boolean active;

    //getters & setters

}

@Entity
public class Worker extends BaseClass{

    @Column
    private String name;

    //getters & setters

}
```

The `active` field of the base class is a flag for the children entities. Only the active ones should be loaded in the application. Then I've written a generic [Spring Data Proxy interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.4.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html):

```java
public interface Dao<T extends BaseClass, E extends Serializable> extends
        CrudRepository<T, E> {

    Iterable<T> findByActive(Boolean active);

}
```

And this one is the interface that should be for `Worker` data access, properly extending the previous one:

```java
@Transactional
public interface WorkerDao extends Dao<Worker, Long>{}
```

Well, now in my logic layer I've implemented an abstract class which will wrap the common code for *CRUD* operations over my entities. I'll have a service for each of them, but I want just to inherit from the `abstract` one. I want to wire the specific repository for each of the services and provide it to the superclass using an `abstract` method. That's how my superclass is implemented:

```java
public abstract class GenericService<E extends BaseClass>{

    public abstract Dao<E, Long> getDao();

    //Here I've got some common operations for managing 
    //all my application classes, including Worker

}
```

The problem is that the `getDao()` method uses the `E` class parameter, which is guaranteed only to be a child of `BaseClass` and not a `javax.persistence.Entity`. When I try to access the DAO from my custom service implementation I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.lang.Iterable com.mycompany.model.daos.interfaces.Dao.findByActive(java.lang.Boolean)!
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:93)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.mycompany.model.BaseClass
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:203)

Which makes sense, because `E` is defined as a child of `BaseClass`. The compiler allows me to write this too:

```java
public abstract class GenericService<E extends BaseClass && Entity>
```

However I get an error in the child Service that says `Worker` class is not compatible with the signature for `E`. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: *which is guaranteed only to be a BaseClass* No, it should be the type that the concrete manager specifies, in this case `Worker`.

Comment: @cy3er correct. It's guaranteed to be a child of `BaseClass`. However, JPA is looking for an `@Entity` and `BaseClass` is a mere `@MappedSuperclass`.

Comment: [This similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415551/generic-spring-data-jpa-repository-implementation-to-load-data-by-class-type) has solved my issue. It was a matter of annotating the abstract repository as `@NoRepositoryBean`. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11012490/1199132) resolves what I was asking for, an annotation-restricted type is not possible.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's just a matter of annotating the abstract `Repository` as `@NoRepositoryBean`:

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface Dao<T extends BaseClass, E extends Serializable> extends
        CrudRepository<T, E> {

    Iterable<T> findByActive(Boolean active);

}
```

This way Spring relies on the underlying repository implementation to execute the `findByActive` method.

Regarding to the annotation type restriction issue, **it's not possible to declare an annotation restricted type**. See the referenced answers below.

**See also:**

- [Generic Spring Data JPA repository implementation to load data by class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415551/generic-spring-data-jpa-repository-implementation-to-load-data-by-class-type)
- [Annotations: restrict reference to classes with a annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011783/annotations-restrict-reference-to-classes-with-a-annotation/11012490#11012490)

Comment: That annotation was the only missing piece in my implementation, you have just saved me after a long embarrassing headache :D...thank you man !

Comment: Ypu man, are a hero. Thanks. Was missing this.