# In Spring data JPA ,How to query data from a table without a repository for entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to fetch data from a table without creating a JPA repository for this specific table.
I need to do this as there are considerable number of entities which I have to do a simple query , it would be a waste to create repositories for each of them.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'm not sure what you mean by "create repositories for each of them". Are you talking about creating a entity for each table?

Comment: May be you can try  with `JDBCTemplate`.if you  don't want have specific repository.

Comment: @Rentius2407 what i mean is creating an interface  that extends jpa repository or crud repository.for each db entity i need to access. I already have jpa entities.

Comment: If you do not want a repository per table/entity you can create a entity manager from your data source and a repository per business requirement and inject the entity manager into that repository. You can then query any entity from the injected entity manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply inject an `EntityManager` to any component:

```
@Component
class SomeComponent {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public List<SomeEntity> findAllEntities() {
        TypedQuery<SomeEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM SomeEntity e", SomeEntity.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Also, if your entities have the same superclass, you can use the same Repository for all of them, like described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420519/common-spring-jpa-repository-with-multiple-entity-finders).

Comment: entityManager.find requires the class to be an entity. Not an answer.

Comment: @K.Nicholas edited a little. Author says "there are considerable number of entities which I have to do a simple query"

Comment: Thank you all , i could get the work done by using Entity manager from persistence context.