# Spring data repository use abstract super class for subclass with different Id

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have few tables with different @Id names but save with similar logic. I want to create a common repository for them.

```java
public interface MachineRepository extends JpaRepository<Machine, Long> {}
```

The entity classes are like this:

Abstract class `Machine`

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Machine{ 
}
```

Entity class `Computer`, which has the same column fields as `server` except the id name.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "computer")
public class Computer extends Machine{
 
    @Id
    Long computerId;
 
    String name;    

    // same getter & setter ...
}
```

Entity class `Server`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "server")
public class Server extends Machine{
 
    @Id
    Long serverId;
 
    String name;    

    // getter & setter...
}
```

I want to save like this:

```java
Machine computer = new Computer();
machineRepository.save(computer);

Machine server = new Server();
machineRepository.save(server);
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: you can not do like above. you can not do it within one repository because the child entity class may have different columns any you should have a different repository for Server and computer.

Comment: What if the other column fields are exactly the same, except for the `computerId` and `serverId`?

Comment: Then we can try to create one Repository as Type as Machine. And I hope that Id as int. Any way you extending those with Machine know. Try to save two type object with that one repository.

Comment: Most probably you wouldn't get any error I think due inheritance.

Comment: I hit an error for not defining IdClass for `machine`. But if I add `@Id computerId` for abstract class `machine`, it is not the case for `server`.

Comment: Hey wait here is your answer...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545276/how-to-implement-a-spring-data-repository-for-a-mappedsuperclass

Comment: Follow above link