# GenericRepository in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jparepository

I'm working with Springboot Application and I've created a genericRepository and all my Repository extend from it and inside the generic repository I defined findByIdAndName(String id,String name) function.My problem is when starting the application it failes because not all entities Have a name attribute But other entities Have it.can I find a way to keep putting the function inside the generic repository? is there any anotation or sth to avoid the runtime error,here's the repo code

```
    
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

import com.mobinets.nep.client.backend.repository.AbstractEntityRepository;
@NoRepositoryBean

public interface GenericCatalogRepository<E,ID> extends AbstractEntityRepository<E,ID> {
    Optional<E> findByIdAndName(String id,String name);
}
```

does anyone face simillar problem before,Thanks in advance

Comment: I did something similar years ago, but I guess you need to have the attribute in all the entities https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545276/how-to-implement-a-spring-data-repository-for-a-mappedsuperclass

Comment: Also, please attach your code as code formatting in the question, not as an image.

Comment: Thanks @Aritz for the reply, in my case, not all entities have name attribute and I can't add the name to to all entities. I'm looking for a way to solve the problem without changing the entities.

Answer (score 1):

In my perspective, it appears to be somewhat of an overhead, especially considering it might not qualify as a high-level abstraction for all cases, particularly when not every entity possesses a 'name' field. While one potential solution that comes to mind involves the creation of multiple GenericCatalogRepositories (one for entities with a 'name' field and another for those without), it still introduces a degree of unnecessary complexity.

**I propose an alternative approach: refrain from overusing generics and instead, opt for the creation of dedicated repositories for each entity**. These repositories can extend the default JPA repositories (e.g., JpaRepository). While this might result in some duplicated code, especially in the context of searching by name, I believe it's a manageable trade-off and doesn't pose a significant problem.